# OpenCVで走行中の車両をカウントする方法について

Tags: c++, c, opencv, raspberry-pi

OpenCVで走行中の車両をカウントする方法には, どのような手法があるのか教えてください.

Comment: 有効な回答を得るには「動体をカウント」をもう少し詳細かつ具体的に説明されたほうが良いと思います。例) 監視カメラ画像からの移動人物別のトラッキングなど

Comment: 「車以外の動体であれば判別出来ている(車の認識をどうすればいいのか分からない)」、もしくは「そもそも動体をカウントする方法が分からない」など条件が何通りか考えられます。

Answer (score 1):

要件がふんわりしているので、関連参考情報の紹介にとどめます。車両カウントは割とメジャーなタスクですから、キーワード「Vehicle Counting OpenCV」や「Vehicle Tracking OpenCV」でWeb検索するといくつか解説記事等が見つかるかと思います。

OpenCV実装例が紹介されているページ：

- [Tutorial: Making Road Traffic Counting App based on Computer Vision and OpenCV](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/tutorial-making-road-traffic-counting-app-based-on-computer-vision-and-opencv-166937911660)
- [StackOverflow - Counting Cars OpenCV + Python Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36254452/684921)